# How to remove nan values from a dataframe column when notnull, dropna and != 'nan' don't work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe with the following columns and datatypes:

```
np_id                     object
target_id                 object
activity_type             object
activity_value            object
activity_units            object
assay_cell_type           object
SMILES                    object
standard_inchi_key        object
standard_inchi            object
target_type               object
target_name               object
target_organism_tax_id    object
target_organism           object
uniprot_id                object
dtype: object
```

`df.uniprot_id` looks like this:

```
0            [nan]
1         [Q96KQ7]
2            [nan]
3         [P25779]
4            [nan]
            ...   
493830       [nan]
493831       [nan]
493832       [nan]
493833       [nan]
493834       [nan]
```

And `df['uniprot_id'].isnull().values.any()` gives `False`

I want to remove all rows which do not have a uniprot_id. I've tried the following:

`df.dropna(subset=['uniprot_id'], inplace=True)`

`df = df[df['uniprot_id'] != 'nan']`

`df = df[df['uniprot_id'] != 'NaN']`

`df[df.uniprot_id.notnull()]`

Why are my attempts not working? How do I remove the nan values, and therefore the rows from the dataframe?

Comment: As far as I understand your `[nan]` values are lists of (one) element `nan`, isn't it? Use @Tom answer to replace them before `dropna`. Keep in mind that @Tom understands those are (`'[nan]'`) strings, I think those are lists...regardless, the concept is that (_you don't have pure `nan`/`None` objects in those cells_)

Comment: @Brandt you are probably right actually, I just said string as that is what happened when I used pd.read_clipboard() after copying his example df but after some testing it is very likely a list holding specificly a np.nan (rather than a None)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[nan]` is being formatted as a list of nan. Replace it with true nan values like so:

```
nan_locs = pd.isnull(df['uniprot_id'].apply(lambda x: x[0]))
df['uniprot_id'][nan_locs] = np.nan
```

Then your code should work. However you may also want to look at just taking every item out of being in a list instead, unless there is a reason for them being in a list:

```
df['uniprot_id'] = df['uniprot_id'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Hey, I used your code followed by `df.dropna(subset=['uniprot_id'], inplace=True)` and I still have `[nan]` in the columns. What else can I try?

Comment: @Gabriel I modified my code, hopefully that works